# Why are there suddenly multiple "Inspect views" in my Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Why did multiple "Inspect views" suddenly appear in my (in-development) Chrome extension (in Chrome 76)? As far as I can tell, when I click on the views (in the image below), these open the specific tab and show the console. However, since these are views for the **content scripts** (not the background scripts) it is confusing. Are there different instances of the background scripts running now? Will it cause performance issues? How to disable them? Will they appear in the packaged extension as well?

**Update** Attaching summary of `manifest.json` and screenshot of Task Manager with multiple instances of my extension - this is all new as of this week.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Tally",
    "version": "0.2.9",
    "icons": {
        "48": "assets/img/icons/tally_icon_48x48.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "assets/img/icons/tally_icon_16x16.png",
        },
        "default_title": "Tally",
        "default_popup": "assets/pages/popup/popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
// scripts
        ]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": [
// scripts
        ],
        "css": [
// scripts
        ],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }],
    "permissions": [
        "*://*/*",
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "management",
        "https://www.google-analytics.com/"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "*.svg", "*.png",
        "*.jpg", "*.JPG",
        "*.gif", "*.GIF",
        "/assets/*",
        "/assets/sounds/*"
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens if you reload the extension?

Comment: It always showed pages/frames that have chrome-extension:// URL of your extension. I see nothing changed about that. No content scripts are shown there. If not a bug, must be something in your extension. Show your manifest.json.

Comment: @PrerakSola reloading extension changes nothing

Comment: @wOxxOm I added the manifest.json - I'm not sure what you mean? I've been working on this ext. >1 year and have never seen any link there besides the background page. Also, note I added screenshot of Task Manager which shows multiple instances. This is all new.

Comment: If you add an iframe that points to an html file inside your extension, it would be shown as a view there, and this particular case was always shown there. Nothing should have changed in Chrome 76 compared to 75 in that regard. Try making a new browser persona (that is, an empty profile) and see if it's any different. Also see if you have some chrome://flags changed.

Comment: @wOxxOm I made a new profile, switched to developer mode and loaded my unpacked extension. As soon as I open a new tab in the new profile a new "inspect view" appears with this text: `http:// url (iframe)` - however there are no iframes on this page so I'm confused. I do have Canary running (in addition to chrome with flags) but it shouldn't affect Chrome.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome. Maybe you can report it on https://crbug.com.

Comment: OK, so this is slightly embarrassing because I *did* add an `iframe` in my code while I was testing an issue last week and left it there in a commit. So @wOxxOm thanks to you I eventually found it.